# Disable Google Hangouts notifications for everyone EXCEPT certain people or groups?

Tags: notifications, mute, google-hangouts

I would like to disable Google Hangouts notifications for everyone *except* certain people or groups.

Hangouts is my primary method of messaging, so people often message me throughout the day.  However, when I am work, it's usually best to disable notifications so I don't interrupt my flow...

...the issue is that I also use Hangouts for work, and my boss contacts me through Hangouts fairly often.  When I disable notifications, I miss her messages, and that's not acceptable.

Obviously, it's impractical to go through my list and disable notifications for every single person except my boss.  But I am not sure what else I can to ensure that:

1. **I do *not* receive Hangouts messages unrelated to work**
2. **I *do* receive all messages from my boss immediately**

Any suggestions or assistance is greatly appreciated!

Comment: It looks like, at this time, there is no way to achieve the results I am looking for.  I marked the response @aparente001 gave as accepted only because it was helpful in coming to my personal solution, which is to simply minimize any notifications coming from anyone other than my boss (once minimized, they do not pop up again until I summon them, even if additional messages are received).  This is of course in Google Chrome for desktop.

Hopefully there will be some more advanced notification filters added in the future, but this works for me for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a perfect example of a situation where it is useful to have two email addresses.  It can be quite important to be able to keep personal and work stuff separate.

Comment: This is less of a solution and more of a workaround, as I'd really prefer not to create a second email account.  Still, I hadn't considered that, so I appreciate your response.

Comment: I do think it's the best approach in the long run, even though it wasn't the direction you were thinking in.